# extracting data from xml file using python

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to extract data from a xml file and write it into a text file in a required format. I want the data in the given below format to be written in the text file:

```
bus 616.0 804.0 852 832
car 399.5 630.5 297 259
bus 545.5 983.0 255 54
```

But I am getting the data in this format:

```
[' bus 616.0 804.0 852 832 ', ' car 399.5 630.5 297 259 ', ' bus 545.5 983.0 255 54 ']
```

Here is my python code:

```
import os
from xml.etree import ElementTree
path = 'C:\\Users\\Microsoft\\Desktop\\xmltxt\\xmlfiles'
dirs = os.listdir( path )
savedir='textfiles'
objects =[]
for image_file in (dirs):
    if not os.path.isdir(savedir):
        os.mkdir(savedir)


    dom=ElementTree.parse(os.path.join(path, image_file))
    labels=dom.findall('object')
    for lbl in labels:
       obj_struct = {}
       name=lbl.find('name').text
       bbox = lbl.find('bndbox')
       xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax = int(bbox.find('xmin').text),int(bbox.find('ymin').text),int(bbox.find('xmax').text),int(bbox.find('ymax').text)
       midx=(xmax+xmin)/2
       midy=(ymax+ymin)/2
       wid=abs(xmax-xmin)
       hgt=abs(ymax-ymin)


       values=(' {} {} {} {} {} '.format(name,midx,midy,wid,hgt))
       print (values)
       objects.append(values)




    save_path = os.path.join(savedir, image_file.replace('xml', 'txt'))
    with open(save_path, 'w') as temp_xml:

        temp_xml.write(str(objects))
```

Comment: I am unable to get the proper output format.See above I have clearly mention the output formats.

Comment: Can you add the sample XML? This will help reproduce and also test alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`objects` is a list. So if you write it, you are going to get the reproduction of a list. But you actually want each line separately.

You will want to change your output code to something like this:

```
with open(save_path, 'w') as temp_xml:
    temp_xml.write('\n'.join([str(x).strip() for x in objects]))
```

Update: As mentioned, some of this shouldn't be needed, if this line removes the spaces:

```
   values=(' {} {} {} {} {} '.format(name,midx,midy,wid,hgt))
```

should be

```
   values=('{} {} {} {} {}'.format(name,midx,midy,wid,hgt))
```

Then it could be simplified to

```
with open(save_path, 'w') as temp_xml:
    temp_xml.write('\n'.join(objects))
```

Comment: Can this not be simplified by removing the spaces when creating  values and thus not needing strip() and also x is already a string.

Comment: Yes, that would be easier (wasn't sure if they were definitely string, but went back and read the code - editing question)